# Retrieving more than 100 message ids from Gmail API

Tags: c#, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have 3000 emails in my gmail account. I want to create an aggregated list of all the senders so that I can more effectively clean up my inbox. I dont need to download the message bodys or the attachments.

I used this sample to get me started (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet) althought now I cant figure out how to return more than 100 message ids when i execute this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Requests;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace GmailQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Gmail API .NET Quickstart";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Gmail API service.
            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });


            ////get all of the message ids for the messages in the inbox
            var messageRequest = service.Users.Messages.List("me");
            messageRequest.LabelIds = "INBOX";

            var messageList = new List<Message>();

            ListMessagesResponse messageResponse1 = new ListMessagesResponse();
            var k = 0;

            do
            {
                messageResponse1 = messageRequest.Execute();
                messageList.AddRange(messageResponse1.Messages);

                var output = $"Request {k} - Message Count: {messageList.Count()} Page Token: {messageRequest.PageToken} - Next Page Token: {messageResponse1.NextPageToken}";
                Console.WriteLine(output);
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\000\log.txt", output);

                messageRequest.PageToken = messageResponse1.NextPageToken;
                k++;

                //this switch allowed me to walk through getting multiple pages of emails without having to get them all
                //if (k == 5)
                //{
                //    break;
                //}

            } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(messageRequest.PageToken));

            //once i created the list of all the message ids i serialized the list to JSON and wrote it to a file
            //so I could test the next portions without having to make the calls against the above each time
            var serializedMessageIdList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageList);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\000\MessageIds.json", serializedMessageIdList);


            //read in the serialized list and rehydrate it to test the next portion
            var mIdList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Message>>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\000\MessageIds.json"));

            //this method takes those message ids and gets the message object from the api for each of them
            //1000 is the maximum number of requests google allows in a batch request
            var messages = BatchDownloadEmails(service, mIdList.Select(m => m.Id), 1000);


            //again i'm serializing the message list and writing them to a file
            var serializedMessageList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messages);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\000\Messages.json", serializedMessageList);

            //and then reading them in and rehydrating the list to test the next portion
            var mList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Message>>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\000\Messages.json"));

            //then i loop through each message and pull the values out of the payload header i'm looking for
            var emailList = new List<EmailItem>();

            foreach (var message in mList)
            {
                if (message != null)
                {
                    var from = message.Payload.Headers.SingleOrDefault(h => h.Name == "From")?.Value;
                    var date = message.Payload.Headers.SingleOrDefault(h => h.Name == "Date")?.Value;
                    var subject = message.Payload.Headers.SingleOrDefault(h => h.Name == "Subject")?.Value;

                    emailList.Add(new EmailItem() { From = from, Subject = subject, Date = date });
                }
            }

            //i serialized this list as well
            var serializedEmailItemList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailList);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\000\EmailItems.json", serializedEmailItemList);

            //rehydrate for testing
            var eiList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmailItem>>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\000\EmailItems.json"));

            //here is where i do the actual aggregation to determine which senders i have the most email from
            var senderSummary = eiList.GroupBy(g => g.From).Select(g => new { Sender = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count);

            //serialize and output the results
            var serializedSummaryList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(senderSummary);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\000\SenderSummary.json", serializedSummaryList);
        }

        public static IList<Message> BatchDownloadEmails(GmailService service, IEnumerable<string> messageIds, int chunkSize)
        {
            // Create a batch request.
            var messages = new List<Message>();

            //because the google batch request will only allow 1000 requests per batch the list needs to be split
            //based on chunk size
            var lists = messageIds.ChunkBy(chunkSize);

            //double batchRequests = (2500 + 999) / 1000;

            //for each list create a request with teh message id and add it to the batch request queue
            for (int i = 0; i < lists.Count(); i++)
            {
                var list = lists.ElementAt(i);

                Console.WriteLine($"list: {i}...");
                var request = new BatchRequest(service);

                foreach (var messageId in list)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine($"message id: {messageId}...");
                    var messageBodyRequest = service.Users.Messages.Get("me", messageId);
                    //messageBodyRequest.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Metadata;

                    request.Queue<Message>(messageBodyRequest,
                        (content, error, index, message) =>
                        {
                            messages.Add(content);
                        });
                }

                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("ExecuteAsync");
                //execute all the requests in the queue
                request.ExecuteAsync().Wait();

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }

            return messages;
        }
    }

    public class EmailItem
    {
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }

    public static class IEnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ChunkBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int chunkSize)
        {
            return source
                .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
                .GroupBy(x => x.Index / chunkSize)
                .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

The research I've done says I need to use a batch request and based on the information I've found Im not able to adapt it to what I'm trying to accomplish. My understanding is that I would use the batch request to get all of the message ids and then 3000 individual calls to get the actual from, subject, and date received from each email in my inbox??

Comment: gmail-api only allow 100 messages for regular users. To get all your messages you need go premium, see [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota)

Comment: the code above has been modified. instead of the broken code I have provided the code that I used to get this working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use paging to get a full list.

Pass the page token from the previous page to get the next call to [`Users.Messages.List`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) (don't pass into the first call to get things started). Detect the end when the result contains no messages.

This allows you to get all the messages in the mailbox.

**NB.** I suggest you make the code async: if there are more than a few messages to read, it can take an appreciable time to get them all.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I edited my original post to include my full code sample before I saw raidensan's comment.

Comment: Note I'm using `Messages.List` (not get) here: it returns a `pageToken` to allow the next page to be retrieved. (`.List` returns less information, but once you have the thread & message ids you can use `.Get` to get the full content.)

Comment: Your answer doesn't address his request about using a batching reqeuest.

Comment: @DaImTo because getting a list of message ids is best done with a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use PageStreamer to get the remainder of the results.

```
var pageStreamer = new PageStreamer<Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message, UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest, ListMessagesResponse, string>(
            (request, token) => request.PageToken = token,
            response => response.NextPageToken,
            response => response.Messages);
var req = service.Users.Messages.List("me");
req.MaxResults = 1000;
foreach (var result in pageStreamer.Fetch(req))
    {
            Console.WriteLine(result.Id);
    }
```

This code will continue to run as long as there are additional results to request.  [Batching](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) isnt really going to help you here as there is no way to know what the next page token will be.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this works for me:

```
Boolean EndOfMessagePages = false;
String pageToken = null;
UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List(EMAIL_ADDRESS);
IList<Message> msgs = null;
ListMessagesResponse lmr;
while (!EndOfMessagePages) { 
    try
    {
        if (pageToken != null)
            request.PageToken = pageToken;

        request.MaxResults = 500; //500 messages at a time instead of the default 100
        lmr = request.Execute();
        msgs = lmr.Messages;
        pageToken = lmr.NextPageToken;

        //If there is no page token at this point, then we have no more pages
        if (pageToken == null)
            EndOfMessagePages = true;
    }
    catch (TokenResponseException trx)
    {
        //Need to delete the token.json folder and re-fetch credentials
        break;
    }
    if (msgs == null || msgs.Count == 0)
        break;

    foreach (Message msg in msgs)
    {
        String ID = msg.Id;
        ...
```